# Adding jQuery to a 3rd party page fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying out a few things, and among those I tried to insert jquery on a site, namely, http://www.tesco.com/wine.

For some reason, I was not able to able access jQuery even though I was able to successfully append a new script tag to the body element.  Also, the page seems to have a `window.$` function that I tried to delete with `delete window.$`. This, seems to return false for me. How do you make something undeleteable?

Here is the code I used to append the jQuery script to the document:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

It is working on other pages.

Comment: Please show the code that includes the jQuery.js. And a sample of the code that tries to use it.

Comment: And how are you running this code on Tesco's website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussing this in JavaScript chat, [Tim Stone discovered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1834389#1834389) that the JS on the page adds its own implementation of `Object.prototype.extend` - which breaks the jQuery script.  To fix it (but potentially break another script on the page), you can delete that before adding jQuery:

```
delete Object.prototype.extend;
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

---

`$` is already defined on that page with the following function declaration:

```
function $(A){return document.getElementById(A)}
```

It is not uncommon to alias `document.getElementById()` with `$()` — in fact, Firebug and WebKit's developer tools do this in their console.

It is not deletable, because it is declared as a `function` statement and not an object property.  While `delete` may work in some browsers, it shouldn't and won't in others.  That being said, I was able to override the function with a simple assignment:

```
$ = function () {}
```

When jQuery loads, it creates the `jQuery` namespace and aliases this namespace with `$`.  Therefore, if something else on the page is overriding `$`, you can still use `jQuery()`.

Comment: If you try using the code I have mentioned, jQuery does not load, on the page. so I am still stuck in trying to use jQuery.

Comment: @Amit: I've updated my answer with the cause of, and a solution to, the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `$` is already defined, you can always use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: I know, my point is you can just refrain from using $ and use jQuery instead, as in `$("#foo")` becomes `jQuery("#foo")`

Comment: i would, but my major problem is, jQuery is also not available either.